# How to define an on change listener for material-ui <CustomInput...>?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, eslint

I'm using the React dashboard built by Creative Tim. My confusion is how do I define an onChange listener for a

The custom input class is defined as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import classNames from "classnames";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
// @material-ui/core components
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
// @material-ui/icons
import Clear from "@material-ui/icons/Clear";
import Check from "@material-ui/icons/Check";
// core components
import customInputStyle from "assets/jss/material-dashboard-react/components/customInputStyle.jsx";

function CustomInput({ ...props }) {
  const {
    classes,
    formControlProps,
    labelText,
    id,
    labelProps,
    inputProps,
    error,
    success
  } = props;

  const labelClasses = classNames({
    [" " + classes.labelRootError]: error,
    [" " + classes.labelRootSuccess]: success && !error
  });
  const underlineClasses = classNames({
    [classes.underlineError]: error,
    [classes.underlineSuccess]: success && !error,
    [classes.underline]: true
  });
  const marginTop = classNames({
    [classes.marginTop]: labelText === undefined
  });
  return (
    <FormControl
      {...formControlProps}
      className={formControlProps.className + " " + classes.formControl}
    >
      {labelText !== undefined ? (
        <InputLabel
          className={classes.labelRoot + labelClasses}
          htmlFor={id}
          {...labelProps}
        >
          {labelText}
        </InputLabel>
      ) : null}
      <Input
        classes={{
          root: marginTop,
          disabled: classes.disabled,
          underline: underlineClasses
        }}
        id={id}
        {...inputProps}
      />
      {error ? (
        <Clear className={classes.feedback + " " + classes.labelRootError} />
      ) : success ? (
        <Check className={classes.feedback + " " + classes.labelRootSuccess} />
      ) : null}
    </FormControl>
  );
}

CustomInput.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  labelText: PropTypes.node,
  labelProps: PropTypes.object,
  id: PropTypes.string,
  inputProps: PropTypes.object,
  formControlProps: PropTypes.object,
  error: PropTypes.bool,
  success: PropTypes.bool
};

export default withStyles(customInputStyle)(CustomInput);
```

My usage of the CustomInput class is as follows:

```
    renderInput(key) {
    return (
      <GridItem xs={20} sm={20} md={12}>
        <CustomInput
          labelText={key}
          id={key}
          inputRef={() => console.log("value changed!")}
          formControlProps={{
            fullWidth: true
          }}
          inputProps={{
            disabled: false
          }}
        />
      </GridItem>
    );
  }
```

When I type something into the input bar I want the message "value changed!" to appear in the console. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the input's `onChange` handler.

Try the snippet below. I hope it helps.

```js
const Input = () => 
  <input onChange={e => console.log(e.target.value)}/>

ReactDOM.render( <Input /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: How can I achieve this using the material-ui classes?

Comment: Adding  onClick={() => console.log("value changed!")} to my <CustomInput ...> doesn't work

Comment: According to the documentation something like onChange={e => console.log("value changed!")}  should work

Comment: onChange
func

Callback fired when the value is changed.

Signature:
function(event: object) => void
event: The event source of the callback. You can pull out the new value by accessing event.target.value.

Comment: But nothing appears in the console

Comment: My full code is         <CustomInput
          labelText={key}
          id={key}
          onChange={(e) => console.log("lol")}
          formControlProps={{
            fullWidth: true
          }}
          inputProps={{
            disabled: false
          }}
        />

Comment: You can put the console.log code in your handler - that will work yes :) The thing is that your `<CustomInput>` component doesn't have its own `onChange` handler. Only its child does i.e. the material-ui input. So you need to pass this call to `console.log` down via props to the material-ui component's `onChange` handler. Here is another demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/jz28w7v01w - I'm passing the `handleChange` prop to the material-ui `<Input/>` component, which uses the prop in its `onChange` handler. Also if you are using chrome, make sure to look in the info tab of your console.

Comment: You can call this prop `onChange` instead of `handleChange`, but I think it's good practice not rename custom props after native handlers. It will get confusing when your app scales.

Comment: With this particular component wrapper, you need to pass `onChange` via `inputProps`: `inputProps={{ onChange: e => console.log(e) }}`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting onChange inside inutProps worked for me

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log("Inside handlChange, event=" + event);
}
                    <CustomInput
                      labelText="* Email..."
                      id="email"
                      formControlProps={{
                        fullWidth: true,
                      }}
                      inputProps={{
                        onChange: (e) => handleChange(e),
                        type: "email",
                        endAdornment: (
                          <InputAdornment position="end">
                            <Email className={classes.inputIconsColor} />
                          </InputAdornment>
                        ),
                      }}
                    />
```

Refer https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit-react/issues/6 for more information